# How to access the object mapped using $data in knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am mapping the subjects object to the li element using knockout attribute mapping as given below.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="subjects">
    <!-- ko foreach:Subjects -->
    <li data-bind='attr:{"data-event":$data}'>
        <a href="#" data-bind='text:subject_name + " by " + teacher_name;'>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

After that I have to access the subject object using the JQuery methods.

```
var originalEventObject = $(element).data('event');
```

**Note:** "element" is correctly here. The code is inside a loop and don't want to complicate the question by having full code here.

But always getting string as [Object Object] but not real JSON. Please help me on this.

Comment: Try `<li data-bind='attr:{"data-event": ko.toJSON($data)}'>`

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not good practice to access data such way. In case of drag & drop it depends is you clone element or not. But you can to this on drag start in case in you use clone. Just override "helper" function in draggable. And then put this data using jQuery if you need:

- > ko.dataFor
- > ko.contextFor

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLX4q/)

```
$(function() {
var model = {
    Subjects: [{text:'first'}, {text: 'second'}]
};
ko.applyBindings(model);
$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(ko.dataFor($('li')[0])));
```

});

Comment: Sorry for the misleading click binding. I removed it now. I actually need to access the data binded outside in a JQuery drop function when the "li" element is dragged and dropped.